# SQL - completing with spaces if NULL?

Tags: sql

Currently trying to write a query, and wanting to  complete a field with spaces if it is NULL.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM (X)
WHERE YEAR = @TaxYear              
LEN(SortCode) > 6 and ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(SortCode,1,6)) = 1
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you include your attempt and what (if anything) goes wrong please. Read [this](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you aren't sure what I'm asking you to change!

Comment: Probably just a minor typo/pasting error, but the above query seems to be missing `AND` or `OR` between the last two lines...

Answer (score 1):

To replace a null value with six spaces use `COALESCE(columnName, '      ')`

Comment: Wouldn't `INSULL` work here, also?  COALESCE is typically used when there's more than one value, right?

Comment: Yes, there is more than one value, it's quite a large query and I'm just trying to insert 'spaces' into the DB IF empty.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer they would both work. `COALESCE` is like a more flexible version of `ISNULL`.

Comment: `COALESCE` is ANSI SQL, so should work on most DBMS, `ISNULL` is TSQL, so is specific to MSSQL Server